# Need to hide title onhover for string in span

Tags: html, css

I have a title in place for a custom fieldset. "customtag" has its own title. Inside this i have a string displayed under span and for this string i have a custom tooltip in place.

When i hover over the text on the string, i see the custom tooltip and title app

```
<customtag title="sample-title">
    <span class="truncated-field-name">
        <md-tooltip ng-bind="field_name"></md-tooltip>
    </span>
</customtag>
```

Please refer the image below. Along with the custom tooltip, "Metrics" which is title "property" is also getting displayed,
If i can hide "Metrics" that would solve my problem.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: use this where there is "metrics" `<!--metrics-->` may that will work.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I get it right... Maybe your easiest solution is to just not add the title attribute to the span.

If this is not an option try using JS to add a mouseenter function that removes the title onHover: (jQuery)

```
$('customtag["title"]').on('mouseenter', function(e){
   $(this).removeAttr("title");
});
```